# Nested Model building

Tags: regression, mixed-model, anova, nested-models

I am trying to write the model which is like this.Suppose you have a nested design (B nested within A), but the number of levels of B can change, depending on the level of A. In addition, the sample sizes may differ. So, for the ith level of A, there are bi levels
of B, and n ij replicates in the ijth cell.
This is the model I am thinking would be,yij = μ + Ai + Bij + eij,
can anyone help me?